# ExactTarget e-mails inconsistently rendering Korean or Chinese characters

Tags: character-encoding, html-email, cjk, exacttarget

I have a small ASP.Net MVC site that is scraping content from a client site for inclusion in an ExactTarget-generated e-mail. If a content area uses hard coded Chinese or Korean characters, the e-mails render properly on all clients. When an area calls to the MVC site, using

```
%%before; httpget; 1 "http://mysite/contentarea/?parm1=One&parm2=Two"%%
```

the resulting html being sent out doesn't render consistently on all clients. GMail handles it ok, but Yahoo and Hotmail do not. The resulting characters make it look like an encoding issue. I have the MVC site spitting out utf-8 à la

```
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

This is the first time I've really had to play with the encoding, so that may be part of my problem. :-)

I've looked at the wiki at http://wiki.memberlandingpages.com/ but it has not been much help. What I'd like do is define in the AMPscript that the incoming stream from the MVC site is encoded utf-8 (or whatever). I'm assuming having things explicitly laid out should address this, but I don't know if there's something about Hotmail or Yahoo that needs to be managed somehow as well. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

The only way (that I've found) to set the character encoding in Exacttarget is to request that they turn on internationalization settings for your account. Email them to let them know that you need that turned on and they should be able to sort you out soon.

Here's some documentation on it:

http://wiki.memberlandingpages.com/010_ExactTarget/020_Content/International_Sends?highlight=internationalization

You'll then have a drop-down when creating an email to specify the character encoding. I banged my head against the wall on this one for a long time before finding that documentation page. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but just in case people are still hunting. I think beyond globalization of ET the httpget function will default to a WindowsCodePage 1252 encoding unless the source page headers specify utf-8 encoding.

http://wiki.memberlandingpages.com/010_ExactTarget/020_Content/AMPscript/AMPscript_Syntax_Guide/HTTP_AMPscript_Functions

"**NOTE**: ExactTarget honors any character set returned in the HTTP headers via Content-Type. For example, you can use a UTF-8 encoded HTML file with Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 included in the header. **If the encoding is not specified in the header, the application assumes all returned data will be in the character set WindowsCodePage 1252**. You can change this default by contacting Global Support."